# Get ng-bootstrap to work for angular cli project with npm

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I am trying to set up a project using angular CLI with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) working. However, I cant get the style to work at all. Here is the exact steps I took (which is the step from the get-started page)

1. Create a new project using - ng new testApp
2. According to the get started pages of ng-bootstrap, I need bootstrap 4 pre-installed. So i run npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
3. Then I run npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
4. Follow the get started guide and did the following to my app.module.ts file

   import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
     imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule {
   }
5. At this point my setup should be ready. So I grab the [Date Picker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker) HTML and TS code and and put it in my app.component.ts and app.compoennt.html file

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const now = new Date();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  date: { year: number, month: number };

  selectToday() {
    this.model = { year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate() };
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p>Simple datepicker</p>

<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>

<hr/>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="selectToday()">Select Today</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="dp.navigateTo()">To current month</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="dp.navigateTo({year: 2013, month: 2})">To Feb 2013</button>

<hr/>

<pre>Month: {{ date.month }}.{{ date.year }}</pre>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

6. run ng serve and this is the result
   [image: output image 1]
   [image: output image 2]

Comment: Are you referencing the bootstrap CSS anywhere? If using angular-cli, you can add it to the "scripts" array in the angular-cli.json file.  In the link you provided for angular 2 bootstrap, it mentions Bootstrap CSS as a dependency.

Comment: I added to angular-cli and it worked thanks. Surprised that it was not mentioned in the get started guide....

Comment: Bah.. I said "scripts"... I meant "styles". Either way, I agree.  It would definitely avoid some confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to add in angular-cli.json at styles the bootstrap.min.css

  ```
  "styles": [
      "styles.scss",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   ]
  ```
- You need to import Ng2BootstrapModule at app.module.ts

  ```
  @NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), Ng2BootstrapModule],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

  export class AppModule { }
  ```

Comment: I think you're confusing ng2-bootstrap (which is made by Valor software: https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/) with the official ng-bootstrap: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers.  That being said, I think it's likely the OP isn't including the CSS reference.

Comment: Simply adding in the angular-cli.json worked for me. @silencedmessage, now I am very confused.... should I be using the official  ng-bootstrap  or the valor ng2-bootstrap? They look like the same framework to me

Comment: I always wondered...why wouldnt the get-started page instruct people to add into angular-cli.json file...

Comment: Both are angular 2 ports of Bootstrap (it's the same underlying JS/CSS).  One is just by the people who made Bootstrap, and the other is by devs who didn't want to wait for Bootstrap to be officially ready.  I'm using ng2-bootstrap in a project because the official wasn't ready when we started.  I'm not sure of how much of a difference there is between the two to be honest.